# how to increase font size in Jqgrid(free version )/Free jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Need help on How to increase font size in Jqgrid(free version )/Free jqGrid so that it effect in all parts of grid. ( add,edit,delete, search,view etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `CSS` to change `font-size` of ( add, edit, delete, search, view).

```
.ui-jqdialog {
    font-size: 20px !important; // use you font size here
}
```